# Intellij code formatting converting variable Javadoc from single line to multiline

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1 and It's converting my single line javadocs to multiline javadoc on every single instance variable and static strings. How do I setup the code formatter to keep the comment as single line comments if it fits in single line.

```
/** some java doc **/
```

is getting converted to

```
/** 
 * some java doc 
 */
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never Mind. Got this. There is an option in IntelliJ which says 
"Do not wrap one line comments"

[image]